# Can I bind a Session to a specific schema in SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I work with a postgres database which has multiple (similar) schemas. In my codebase, I reflect the different schemas in seperate `schema_xy.py` files. I also have a `base.py` file which contains a base class with abstract tables definitions, for tables that are present in multiple schemas.

My `base.py` file:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://dbuser@dbhost:5432/dbname')

Base = declarative_base(bind=engine)

class User(Base):
    __abstract__ = True

    id = ..
```

And an example `Schema1.py` file, which inherits the `User` table from base but also has a schema specific table `S1Table`:

```
from sqlalchemy import declarative_base
from .base import User

engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://dbuser@dbhost:5432/dbname')
Schema1Base = declarative_base(bind=engine, metadata=MetaData(schema='Schema1'))

class User(Schema1Base, User):
    __tablename__ = "user"

class S1Table(Schema1Base):
    __tablename__ = "s1table"

    foo = ...
```

My question is, how do I best instantiate sessions for querying and uploading data, which are 'bound' to a specific schema, i.e. how do I make sure that I query/manipulate the `User` table from the correct schema?

I have found this blog post

http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2010/09/10/sqlalchemy-connecting-to-pre-existing-databases/

which defines a `loadSession` function for `Base` like so:

```
def loadSession():

    metadata = Base.metadata
    Session = sessionmaker(bind=engine)
    session = Session()
    return session
```

But I don't understand what the unused `metadata` is supposed to do here exactly.